# дерганое передвижение персонажа в unity на андроид

Tags: unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    private float moveInput;

    public Joystick joystick;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool facingRight = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = joystick.Horizontal;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
        {   
            Flip();
        }
        else if(facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
}
```

на телефоне дергано а на компьютере все плавно подскажите как можно решить

Comment: Может просто на ПК кадров больше выдаёт, вот и изображение кажется более плавным. Или Joystick разный input выдаёт на разных платформах.

Answer (score 0):

решено нужно изменить ограничение кадров с 30 до 60